# Simple "Assign" Function

Tags: verilog, assign

i have just started to learn some verilog and came across a problem that would normally be solved using a for loop in other languages.

```
s2 s1 s0 m
 0  0  0 u
 0  0  1 v
 0  1  0 w
 0  1  1 x
 1  0  0 y
 1  0  1 z
```

This is the truth table of the problem where s2,s1,s0 are switches, (u,v,w,x,y,z) are inputs and if certain switches are set, the output(m) will be set as one of the inputs. However, this is only 1 bit wide and we can just assign each m to be one of the following inputs provided that s0,s1,s2 matches. If it were 3 bit wide input and output ex:(u0,u1,u2),(m0,m1,m2) but each of the variables still follows the same logic with one another(ex: u0,u1,u2 will all be the outputs m0,m1,m2 provided that all switches are 0) how can i shorten my code. Am i allowed to do:

```
assign m[3:0] = (~s0&~s1&~s2&u[3:0])
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not a good solution. Verilog will extend your select signals to be the same width as m before performing the `&` operation, and the default behavior is to add zeros on the left to extend a signal. It might work if you declared the select signals to be signed but I think you can do better.

Furthermore, the example you provide only deals with the first row of your truth table. For the other seven combinations of `s0`, `s1`, and `s2` you would be assigning all zeros to `m`. If you want to do this in a single combinational assignment then you would need 8 logical expressions like the one you have, all ORed together to get the final result.

A much cleaner way of doing this is with an `if-then-else` or `case` statement inside an `always` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try a case statement:

```
always @* begin
  case ({s2,s1,s0})
    3'b000 : m = u;
    3'b001 : m = v;
    3'b010 : m = w;
    3'b011 : m = x;
    3'b100 : m = y;
    3'b101 : m = z;
    default: m = 0; /* <-- catch all */
  endcase
end
```

Note: Use `default` if the truth table is incomplete. Otherwise a latch will be inferred.

Working example: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/187